# Can I have a Windows .exe file version with only three digits?

Tags: windows, version

I'd like to be able to use a three-digit versioning scheme for my application; however, when I set only three digits for both the file version and the product version in my .rc file (both the string and numerical versions), Windows displays the file version as "1.0.0.0" instead of the "1.0.0" that I intended for it to be. What am I doing wrong here?

The pertinent part of my .rc file is:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION VERSION_MAJOR,VERSION_MINOR,VERSION_PATCH
 PRODUCTVERSION VERSION_MAJOR,VERSION_MINOR,VERSION_PATCH
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x0L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Acme Inc."
            VALUE "FileDescription", "My App"
            VALUE "FileVersion", VERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName", "My App.exe"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © 2021 Acme Inc."
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "My App.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "My App"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", VERSION_STR
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END
```

where `VERSION_MAJOR`, `VERSION_MINOR`, `VERSION_PATCH`, and `VERSION_STR` are `#define`s from a header that is autogenerated by CMake.

Comment: [`FILEVERSION` and `PRODUCTVERSION` are four 16-bit integers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource).

Comment: Is that just a fixed requirement that can't be worked around?

Comment: That is part of the file format.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll just have to have an extra zero on the end of the file version string. Unfortunate, but it is what it is. This is why I just use Linux for my daily driver :)

Comment: Technically, you're filling in two 32-bit integers. By convention, the values are interpreted as four 16-bit integers. There's no convention for specifying an alternate presentation. (You could try making one up and seeing if you gain any followers.) You can create a custom "FileVersion" string that says whatever you like. Code which displays the string will show your custom string. (What would the linux way of doing this be? Are file versions just strings that programs aren't expected to parse?)

Comment: Linux just doesn't bother with file versions; the app can say whatever it wants for its version, and the .desktop file used for app integration into the desktop can also have arbitrary data (I think).